# How to predict from ns spline parameters without model object

Tags: r, glm, spline, predict

I have the coefficients from a glm fitted in R, and I want to predict expected values for a new set of data. If I had the model object this would be simple, using predict(). However, I am now offsite and for data confidentiality reasons I no longer have the model object. I have only the summary object, generated using summary(model), which contains the model coefficients.

It's easy enough to use the coefficients to predict expected values for a simple model. However, I would like to know how to do this when the model includes a cubic spline ns(). Any shortcuts for when the model also includes categorical variables would be appreciated as well.

Here is a simple example.

```
library(splines)
dat <- data.frame(x=1:500, z=runif(500), k=as.factor(sample(c("a","b"), size=500, replace=TRUE)))
kvals <- data.frame(kn=c("a","b"),kv=c(20,30))
dat$y = dat$x + (40*dat$z)^2 + kvals$kv[match(dat$k,kvals$kn)] + rnorm(500,0,30)
# Fit model
library(splines)
mod <- glm(y ~ x + ns(z,df=2) + k,data=dat)
# Create new dataset
dat.new <- expand.grid(x=1:3,z=seq(0.2,0.4,0.1),k="b")
# Predict expected values in the usual way
predict(mod,newdata=dat.new)
summ <- summary(mod)
rm(mod)
# Now, how do I predict using just the summary object and dat.new?
```

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101484/11849

Comment: If you are using a function htat is not in the base set you should always add the needed library call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient method to tackle this, but here's a starting point to get you set up to implement the strategy the Roland briefly suggested. The `summ` object has the information necessary to define the spline function, but it's kind of buried:

```
    names(summ)
     [1] "call"           "terms"          "family"         "deviance"       "aic"           
     [6] "contrasts"      "df.residual"    "null.deviance"  "df.null"        "iter"          
    [11] "deviance.resid" "coefficients"   "aliased"        "dispersion"     "df"            
    [16] "cov.unscaled"   "cov.scaled"
```

And looking at the structure of the `terms` leaf, we see that the spline detail is buried deeper still inside the `predvars` subleaf:

```
str(summ$terms)
Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language y ~ x + ns(z, df = 2) + k
  ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(y, x, ns(z, df = 2), k)
  ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:4, 1:3] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "y" "x" "ns(z, df = 2)" "k"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "x" "ns(z, df = 2)" "k"
  ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:3] "x" "ns(z, df = 2)" "k"
  ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:3] 1 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(y, x, ns(z, knots = structure(0.514993450604379, .Names = "50%"), Boundary.knots = c(0.00118412892334163,  0.99828373757191), intercept = FALSE), k)
  ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:4] "numeric" "numeric" "nmatrix.2" "factor"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "y" "x" "ns(z, df = 2)" "k"
```

So pull the attribute out:

```
str(attributes(summ$terms)$predvars)
 language list(y, x, ns(z, knots = structure(0.514993450604379, .Names = "50%"),
               Boundary.knots = c(0.00118412892334163,  0.99828373757191), intercept = FALSE), k)
```

You can see that it is possible to recover the spline if you supply the x,y,z, and k values needed:

```
with(dat, ns(z, knots = 0.514993450604379, Boundary.knots = c(0.00118412892334163, 
 0.99828373757191), intercept = FALSE) )
#---
                 1             2
  [1,] 5.760419e-01 -1.752762e-01
  [2,] 2.467001e-01 -1.598936e-01
  [3,] 4.392684e-01  4.799757e-01
snipping ....
[498,] 4.965628e-01 -2.576437e-01
[499,] 5.627389e-01  1.738909e-02
[500,] 2.393920e-02 -1.611872e-02
attr(,"degree")
[1] 3
attr(,"knots")
[1] 0.5149935
attr(,"Boundary.knots")
[1] 0.001184129 0.998283738
attr(,"intercept")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"class")
[1] "ns"     "basis"  "matrix"
```

You can build a substitute `dat`, if you know the extremes of your data. See `?ns` and the other help pages it links to.